# Declary Countly.q.push inside Typescript declaration file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, declaration, countly-analytics

How I can declare Countly push add_event method like this:

```
Countly.q.push(['add_event',{
  "key":"action_open_web",
}]);
```

inside declaration file (.d.ts). I tried this and does not work:

```
declare module 'countly-sdk-web' {
    export function q.push(
        [string, {key: string,}]
    ): void;
}
```

Reference: [Countly-sdk-web](https://support.count.ly/hc/en-us/articles/360037441932-Web-analytics-JavaScript-#events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
declare module 'countly-sdk-web' {
    type Event = [string, Record<string, string>]
    interface ICountly {
        q: Array<Event>
    }
    const Countly: ICountly
    export default Countly;
}
```